# Can anybody explain the title of this article?

Tags: headlinese

the title is:

"If Everything Is ‘Trauma,’ Is Anything?"

the article:

https://www.nytimes.com/2022/02/04/opinion/caleb-love-bombing-gaslighting-trauma.html

I read throght even with some sort of dificulty but can't make a link with the text with its title

Comment: I can't read the article itself (can't be bothered with NYT's constant nagging to get me to take out a subscription). But I'm sure it's just some reporter's idea of clever "**wordplay**". Don't copy it.

Comment: *If everything is "trauma", is anything ["trauma"]?* The author argues that nowadays the word "trauma" is used loosely, vaguely, particularly on social media, and we need to be more precise in our expressions. If you start calling everything "trauma", you lose the meaning of the word and you can't tell the difference between "a real trauma" and "a so-called trauma".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks for your attention. I'm trying to be more fluid in thinking in English and knowing what this title is intended to convey would help me in the process of building my own sentences, get it? it is a wordplay as you told what is him trying to say?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilk, "If everything is "trauma", is anything ["trauma"]? " how did you make the reasoning of repeating the word trauma after anything ???

Comment: There's no meaningful grammar or syntax here. Arguably it would have been more "grammatical" for the headline to read *If everything is **traumatic**, is anything?* Really, it's just a facile attention-grabbing headline probably making the point that if mainstream media continue with their current trend towards finding evidence of traumatic experiences *everywhere*, they'll end up debasing the meaning of the term. If you classify ***everything*** as "X", the designation "X" eventually ceases to have any meaning whatsoever.

Comment: @henrykearaudjo by asking a question *"is anything **what**?"*

Comment: General rule of thumb: don't post links to paywalled articles. Another helpful tip: don't try to learn grammar from headlines.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I get we ask ourselfs "is anything what" to complete the sentence in our mind as Adrew Tobiko said but differently of most of you my mind came back wth different answer so in my mind it was like: "If Everything Is ‘Trauma,’ Is Anything [NOT TRAUMA]? implying that everything is trauma now a days. SO there is not NOT TRAUMA anymore. Make sense?

Comment: @all, is that a valid interpretation to think of it as "If Everything Is ‘Trauma,’ Is Anything not trauma?" implying EVERY behavioral problem stem from traumas so "NO trauma" is not option anymore?

Comment: @henrykearaudjo: No. No native English speaker would understand the ellipsis "is anything **not** Trauma".